# Cordova Windows Platform

Tags: cordova

I am trying to develop a cross platform windows desktop application. I went through different sites and found that Apache's Cordova platform is best to develop a cross platform hybrid application.

I understand that Cordova can be used to develop WIndows 8.1/ windows 10 store apps, but can I use Cordova platform to develop windows desktop application?

Answer (score 0):

cordova is old technology (for me) for build mobile apps now people use [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) or [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/). And you can't make desktop app in cordova. For make desktop (Windows, OSX, Linux) application use for example [Electron](https://electronjs.org/)

Comment: Thanks Dziadek, Just to clarify that Cordova can be used to develop WIndows Microsoft store apps but not Windows Desktop application right?